# Open and read file in mips

Tags: file, assembly, io, mips, mars-simulator

I'm trying to open and read a file in mips but doesnt show anything. I have the file in same directory as mars.jar and I think the code is right. I tried everything and searched and still it doesnt work. Please help me I really need to deliver this program and I dont know what to do.
This is my code:

```
.data
bin: .asciiz "hundredints.bin"
size: .space 4096
.text
li $v0, 13
la $a0, bin
li $a1, 0
li $a2, 0
syscall
move $s0, $v0

li $v0, 14
move $a0, $s0
la $a1, size
li $a2, 4096
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, size
syscall

li $v0, 16
move $a0, $s0
syscall
```

PS: sorry for my english

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209893/discussion-on-question-by-sonia-cristina-open-and-read-file-in-mips).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct. However, according to [MARS syscall specifications](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html), on issuing a syscall for opening a file, if $v0 gets a negative value, it means there was a problem in opening the file.

You can verify that by assembling the code in MARS, putting a breakpoint on

> move $s0, $v0

and inspecting the contents of $s0 *after* this line executes (or alternatively print $s0 as an integer using syscall 1 in $v0).

If this is negative, (most likely in your case?) - it means the file couldn't be opened by the JAVA process that is MARS.

The above link also says "The underlying file I/O implementation uses java.io.FileInputStream.read() to read and java.io.FileOutputStream.write() to write."

Note that you are trying to open a *relative* path "hundredints.bin" (relative to the MARS Java process's home directory). Hence, **JAVA process MARS should run from the same directory as your code and file that you are trying to open.**

You can do this by issuing the following in *your code-and-file directory* (MAC or Linux, assuming java is installed!)-

> java -jar Mars.jar

(Or an equivalent arrangement in Windows).

Verifying if the MARS JAVA process's home is indeed your code's home-

Just 'open' a file in MARS. It should directly show the contents of your directory. :)

I've tested this in Ubuntu. Hope this helps!